# $(0,1)^n$ a normal space but $(0,1)^{\mathbb{R}}$ not normal?

Tags: general-topology

Is it true that $(0,1)^n$ is a normal space for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
but $(0,1)^{\mathbb{R}}$ is not normal?

This seems like an interesting result and rather counterintuitive and if true would also mean that $(0,1)^{\mathbb{R}}$ is not a metric space.

I came across this as an argument in an answer to an old question but there was no proof of this claim.

How would you prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true. We can replace $(0,1)$ by $\mathbb{R}$ because they are homeomorphic as spaces. Then $\mathbb{R}^I$ is normal exactly if the index set $I$ is at most countable (and then the space is even metrisable). For uncountable $I$ the space is not normal (so certainly not metrisable).

[Here](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2009/10/13/the-uncountable-product-of-the-countable-discrete-space-is-not-normal/) it is shown that $\mathbb{N}^I$ is not normal for uncountable index set, and this is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^I$ so if the latter were normal, the former would be too, which it is not), and this settles it.

The original paper is [here](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183512390), it's theorem 3. It's due to A.H. Stone. The first link is essentially a more expanded write-up of this argument. The whole paper by Stone is worth a read (a classical paper).

Comment: @JKnecht glad you like it!